# Find Product Hackerearth

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote this code for findproduct on hackerearth. When I [compile and test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpkGz.png), it doesn't show any error but when I [submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMHni.png) the code, it shows wrong answer. can someone help me out.

The link for the question:
https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/find-product/description/

```
#include<iostream>     
using namespace std;

int main()

{        
        int n,p=1;    
        cin>>n;     
        int a[n];

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {       
            cin>>a[i];        
    
            p=(p*a[i])%1000000007;

        }          
        cout<<p;           
        return 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong data type. You get an overflow. The maximum number you can get is  1000000007 * 1000000007. This does not fit in an integer and will result in -371520463.

(actually the biggest number is 1000000006)

Please change your data type to unsigned long long.

Your statement `int a[n];` is not C++ compliant. It works per accident with your compiler. But it is not C++.

You also do not need an array at all. You can directly multiply the values, after reading them.

With that you save tons of memory.

One of many possible solutions:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr unsigned long long primeModulo = 1000000007ULL;

int main() {
    
    // Here we will store the result 
    unsigned long long product{ 1 };

    // Read number of values to multiply
    if (size_t numberOfValues{}; std::cin >> numberOfValues)

        // Now, read numberOfValues and multiply them with modulo
        for (size_t i{}; i < numberOfValues; ++i)

            // Read value
            if (unsigned long long value{}; std::cin >> value)

                // Perform multiplication
                product = (product * value) % primeModulo;

    // Show result to user
    std::cout << product;
    return 0;
}
```

---

Rules for modulo arithmetic

```
1. ( a + b ) % c = ( ( a % c ) + ( b % c ) ) % c
2. ( a * b ) % c = ( ( a % c ) * ( b % c ) ) % c
3. ( a – b ) % c = ( ( a % c ) - ( b % c ) ) % c (caveat with negative values!)
4. ( a / b ) % c  NOT EQUAL TO ( ( a % c ) / ( b % c ) ) % c
```